# How do i translate SORT and Match google sheet formula into app script/ javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

How do I run a formula like:

```
=sort(A2:F5000, match(B2:B5000,{"QTA 10 Days","QTA-REMAKE","QTA-SAMPLE","QTA NEW PROJECT","QTA NPI-CVF-Bryan","Qual-QTA-NPI Remake"},0),1)
```

To a range of fields using the Google Apps Script API for Google Sheets?

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort your sheet, you can use the following code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var inSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0];
  var outSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[1];

  var values = inSheet.getRange('A2:C23').getValues();
  values.sort(mySort);

  outSheet.getRange('A2:C23').setValues(values);
}


function mySort(row1, row2) {
  var values = ["QTA 10 Days","QTA-REMAKE","QTA-SAMPLE","QTA NEW PROJECT","QTA NPI-CVF-Bryan","Qual-QTA-NPI Remake"];
  var val1 = values.indexOf(row1[2]);
  var val2 = values.indexOf(row2[2]);
  return val1 - val2;
}
```

You will of course have to change the ranges and/or sheets that you are using. The Sheets file I have used is [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/118grg_kFS1d_i7SxqI98g6gst1BOIJfeAM_qkDOLT3s/edit?usp=sharing) one, where you can see the original values in Sheet1 and the output of running my script in Sheet2.

### Sorting based on starting pattern substring

To sort based on whether the string starts with "QTA" or not, you can substitute the `mySort` function I provided above with the following:

```js
function mySort(row1, row2) {
  var val1 = row1[2];
  var val2 = row2[2];
  var qta1 = val1.indexOf("QTA") == 1;
  var qta2 = val2.indexOf("QTA") == 1;
  if (qta1 === qta2) return  strcmp(val1, val2);
  return qta1 ? 1 : -1;
}

function strcmp(a, b) {
  if (a.toString() < b.toString()) return -1;
  if (a.toString() > b.toString()) return 1;
  return 0;
}
```

This function will prioritise the rows that contain 'QTA', and it will also compare the rest of the the string in case both or neither contain the substring. See Sheet3 of my test sheet for the results.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have a question, how do I make all variables with "QTA" in it's variable name top priority if I have other variables that don't have "QTA" in its name? So that when i sort any variable with "QTA" will appear on top of the sheet.

Comment: @Alvis I have updated my answer with the expected behaviour you described. If that works for you please consider marking the answer as 'accepted'. Cheers